# How to create CSV file from list of dictionaries with different columns

Tags: list, pandas, csv, dictionary, multiple-columns

this is my first question after extensively searching on here. 
I am trying to write a csv file that takes a list of dictionaries where every dictionary has some common keys but mostly varied. Every key should be a column name.

I created a loop that generated a list of all non-repeating keys in order to create a list of column names. I am not sure if this is necessary.

```
IN

data = [{u'A' : u'a', u'B' : u'b' }, {u'A' : u'd', u'C' : u'c'}]
columns = [u'A', u'B', u'C']

OUT
     A   B   C
0   'a' 'b'
1   'd'     'c'
```

After unsuccessfully using DictWriter, I've started using pandas with limited success. Have no clue how to use DataFrame appropriately for this use case.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

```
IN:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)


OUT
     A   B   C
0   'a' 'b'  'c'
1   'a' 'b'  'c'
2   'a' 'b'  'c'
n   'a' 'b'  'c'
```

UPDATE:

Figured it out. I just wasn't producing the list in the same way I had above. I was messing up how I was appending dictionaries. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

The columns will be generated by the keys used in the dictionaries in data

Comment: Hm -- it gives me:

    OUT
         A   B   C
    0   'a' 'b'  'c'
    1   'a' 'b'  'c'
    2   'a' 'b'  'c'
    n   'a' 'b'  'c'

Comment: Are you using the same data that you have in the original comment? I'm not sure how you are arriving at this result

Comment: I'm an idiot. I wasn't producing that list the way I should have. The responses were incredibly helpful in digging for the answer. Thanks!